# How do you display an image on webpage using file path stored on a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, imageurl

I've got a WCF Service Library with all the SQL statements on. A Windows Forms Admin app is updating the Service and an ASP.Net Web Forms app is consuming the Services.

File paths are stored as a strings in the database to change images in the Picture Box on the WinForms app.

I thought I could just pass the filePath into a string variable on the ASP.Net end and use that for `Image.Url`. Its not working.

Whats the simplest way of doing this? Security is not an issue, this is just for an assignment.

When the user changes the Cottage ID the corresponding image should change on the web site.

**C#**

```
 protected void BtnID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxID.Text);

            string fileName = ws.GetImage1FileName(id);

            Image1.ImageUrl = fileName;
    }
```

**Html**

```
 <td class="Column3" colspan="1">
                <asp:Image class="Image" ID="Image1" runat="server"/>
            </td>
```

TIA!

Comment: What is the value of fileName? Is it valid image path?

Comment: @BJohn "G:\bigCottage.jpeg". Thats one of them. The `WinForms` app opens a `OpenFileDialog` box to get the file so on that that side it doesn't really matter where it is. Is Asp.Net not the same?

Comment: asp.net is not the same. Asp.net is for web application which is different from winform desktop application. You couldn't use absolute path  with drive letter.You should use path such as bigCottage.jpeg  or /bigCottage.jpeg, and ensure there is an image named bigCottage.jpeg in your webform application's root path.   For security, web application is for many users , if you could access file through file protocol , this means a webapplication  could access  every user's file system , which is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

assume your data out put as

string fileName = "123.png";

```
    protected void BtnID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxID.Text);

        string fileName = ws.GetImage1FileName(id);

        Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/images") + "/" + fileName;
    }
```

In winforms you can try with Bitmap

```
Image1.Image = new Bitmap(YourFileName);
```

Comment: I call it fileName but I do actually store the whole path in database and return that. Which works well with the `openDialogBox` in `WinForms`. Assuming server.Path won't work with full filePath?